# Calling Javascript code automatically after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript

i want to run similar task for my site. I want to run javascript code when user visit or click my URL, the code should be run after 2 seconds automatically after loading my page.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        your functions()
    },2000);
}
```

Onload function is called after page load complete and setTimeout is used for delayation

Comment: mark this correct if it helped you @KashifNoor :)

Comment: where i have to put this code? i mean which tag should i have to use for it? Body or head tag?

Comment: anywhere @KashifNoor it will run after your page is full loaded

Comment: @KashifNoor can you add this code to your question in comments its unreadable

Comment: my question limit has been finished